# How do you call `request` within a Cypress custom command?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How do you call `request` within a Cypress custom command?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('factory', async (name, attributes) => {
  const response = await cy.request('POST', '/cypress/factories', {
    name,
    attributes: attributes || {}
  });
  return response;
});
```

results in ..

> The command that returned the promise was:  > cy.factory() .
>   The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:  > cy.request() .
>   Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them .
>   or return your own promise.Cypress will resolve your command with .
>   whatever the final Cypress command yields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message says, Cypress will resolve the response for you, so no need to return anything.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('factory',(name, attributes) => {
  cy.request('POST', '/cypress/factories', {
    name,
    attributes: attributes || {}
  });
});
```

You can use the command with `then`

```
cy.factory(name, attributes).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
```